# Insert form fields into form

Tags: forms

i have a form inside an .inc file. That form i'm calling it inside a new form i'm making, using form_load_include, so far is working but its rendering the external form outside the new form. this is the code that does that:

```
<?php
// start form to create projects
function project_creator_form($form, &$form_state) {
    global $user;
    $uuid = $user->uid;

  form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'lc_core', 'location'); //here i call the form
  $renderable = drupal_get_form('location_form', $form_state);
  $location = render($renderable);
  print $location; //here i print the included form

  $form['u_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Identificador de Usuario'),
    '#size' => '6',
    '#attributes' => array('readonly' => 'readonly'),
    '#default_value' => $uuid,
    '#description' => "Este es su identificador de usuario, (no se puede modificar)",
    );

    $form['p_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Nombre de Proyecto'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => "Introduzca el nombre del proyecto.",
    );

    $form['p_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Seleccione tipo de proyecto'),
    '#options' => array(
      'Obra Nueva' => t('Obra Nueva'),
      'Adecuación' => t('Adecuación'),
      'Remodelacion' => t('Remodelación'),
      'Ampliación' => t('Ampliación'),
      'Refuerzo estructural' => t('Refuerzo estructural'),
      'Mantenimientos' => t('Mantenimientos'),
  ),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('Seleccione el tipo de intervención a relizar.'),
    );

    $form['p_area'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Area del proyecto (m2)'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => "Ingrese la cantidad de metros cuadrados (m2) del proyecto.",
    '#size' => '6',
    );

  $form['p_desc'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Descripción'),
    '#description' => "Describa de que se trata el proyecto a ejecutar, puede especificar algunos detalles e información que considere necesaria.",
    '#rows' =>4,
    '#resizable' => FALSE,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['buttons'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Guardar proyecto'),
    );    
  return $form;

}

function project_creator_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    db_set_active('civilproconstru'); //OPEN alter DATABASE.
    db_insert('project_info')
        ->fields(array(
        'u_id' => $form_state['values']['u_id'],
        'p_name' => $form_state['values']['p_name'],
        'p_type' => $form_state['values']['p_type'],
        'p_area' => $form_state['values']['p_area'],
        'p_ctry' => $form_state['values']['p_ctry'],
        'p_dept' => $form_state['values']['p_dept'],
        'p_city' => $form_state['values']['p_city'],
        'p_desc' => $form_state['values']['p_desc'],

        ))->execute();
$p_name=$form_state['values']['p_name'];        
$loglink = l("Ver Proyectos", 'admin/lista_de_proyectos');
$msg= "El proyecto $p_name ha sido indexado, continue ingresando información del proyecto en $loglink o puede seguir indexando nuevos proyectos.";
drupal_set_message($msg);   

db_set_active(); //CLOSE alter DATABASE.
}
```

And this is the output i'm getting:
[image: output]

Despite i'm printing inside the function that is creating the form drupal it's rendering outside of it...

HOW CAN I FIX THIS???? thanks for the help!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the form when you load it, create a new form item of type markup and add your subform there as markup.

```
$form['subform'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => $location,
);
```

This would fix the display order but your submit handler will need to handle the extra items.